# replacing index server with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have created an elasticsearch index against a news table on sqlserver using logstash via the JDBC Driver. This all looks good in Elasticsearch.

Using Index Server, the type of query that gets built for that takes the following form:

```
SELECT News.*, fulltextsearch.rank FROM News INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(News, ( Headline, BodyText ), 'ISABOUT("car track race" WEIGHT(0.65), car NEAR track NEAR race)') fulltextsearch ON News.NewsID = fulltextsearch.[Key] WHERE DateSubmitted <= '01/11/2017' ORDER BY fulltextsearch.rank DESC
```

Is there any kind of query that I can do in Elasticsearch to give a similar/same outcome as the above.

Answer (score 0):

No, elasticsearch (version 5.3) do not support JOIN like this. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html.